# How to establish a connection?

Tags: php, db2

I am new to DB2.

```
$database = 'test';
$user = 'user1';
$password = 'pswd1';
$hostname = '10.250.10.10';
$port = 556;


$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=$database;" .
  "HOSTNAME=$hostname;PORT=$port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=$user;PWD=$password;";
$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', '');


if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection succeeded.";
    db2_close($conn);
}
else {
print($conn);
    echo "Connection failed.";
    die(db2_conn_errormsg());

}
```

all the values are correct. But connection have been failed. Plz advise me. and How to check in the PHPINFO(). whether the DB2 have been installed successfully or not.

I got the following error

```
Connection failed.[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified SQLCODE=0
```

Comment: Db2 connection error is. "Connection failed.[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified SQLCODE=0"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP maven, but if you're using the ODBC driver, you probably need to catalogue the database in the ODBC driver manager.  On Windows, search for ODBC in "Search Programs and Files".  I'm not sure the equivalent on Linux